# 45 base 10 to base 5. I am getting problem problems arriving at an answer.

Tags: algorithms

I am getting problems with this equation

45 base 10 to base 5
I have tried this method
45÷5=9 r 0
9÷5=1 r 4
4÷5= 0 r 4
Ans =440. However when we do the reverse we are not getting 45. Someone please help

Comment: That answer is wrong. The correct answer is $140_{5}$ as your work demonstrates.

Comment: When you got $9 \div 5 = 1 r4$ then need to divide the $1$, the quotient, not the $4$, the remainder.

Comment: So therefore the last one would be it 0 r 1

Answer (score 1):

To convert you divide, keep track of the remainder and then divide the *quotient* and repeat until you get a quotient of $0$.

In you last step you confused a quotient of $1$ with the remainder of $4$.

So first step is $45 \div 5 = 9r 0$ so write down the $0$.  You did that.

Then deal with the quotient.  $9 \div 5 = 1r 4$ so write down the $4$ to get $40$.  You did that.

Then deal with the quotient.  The quotient is $1$.  You did not deal with the quotient.  You dealt with the remainder of $4$.  That was wrong.

$1 \div 5 = 0 r 1$.  So write down the $1$ to get $140$.  And so $140_5 = 45_{10}$ and indeed $1*5^2 + 4*5 + 0*1 = 25 + 20 + 0 = 45$.

---

To keep from getting confused it might help to add a "so that means..." after ever line:

$45\div 5 = 9 r0$:

**so that means** $45 = 9*5 + 0$.

And $9 \div 5 = 1 r 4$

**so that means** $9 = 1*5 + 4$

**and that means**  $45 = 9*5 + 0 = (1*5 + 4)*5 + 0 = 1*5^2 + 4*5 + 0$

And $4 \div 5 = 0 r 4$

**so that means** $4 = 0*5 + 4$

**and that means** $45= 1*5^2 + 4*5 + 0$ and ... **hey! That's a $1$, not a $4$!!!**

So, ...oops...

And $1\div 5 = 0 r 1$

and that means $1 = 0*5 + 1$ so

$45 = (0*5 + 1)*5^2 + 4*5 + 0$ so

$45 = 0*5^3 + 1*5^2 + 4*5 + 0$ and we are done.

$45 = 1*5^2 + 4*5 + 0=140_5$